# How can I evaluate $\int e^u \; u \; \sqrt{\ln \frac{1}{u}\,} \; \mathrm{d}u$?

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, exponential-function

How do I solve the following integration problem:

$$\int e^u \; u \; \sqrt{\ln \frac{1}{u}\,} \; du \;\;\;\;\; ?$$

Comment: Actually, I could not proceed at all with the solution. I faced a dead end at the beginning only !

Comment: While you may feel that your lack of progress ("dead end") occurs at the beginning, you should articulate where you are trying to begin.  Blanket statements that "I could not proceed at all" are apt to give Readers the impression you have not digested the definitions and meaning for the Question and hope to pass through the exercise to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the integration range is $(0,1)$, from
$$ \int_{0}^{1} u^k \sqrt{-\log u}\,du = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2(1+k)^{3/2}} \tag{1} $$
it follows that:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} u e^u\sqrt{-\log u}\,du = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{k!(k+2)^{3/2}}\tag{2} $$
where the RHS of $(2)$ is a fast-converging series. If the integration range is not really specified, you may use differentiation under the integral sign to write your integral as the [semiderivative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Semiderivative.html) of an incomplete $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for the solution that you have provided me with...

But can you provide me with the source of equation no. (1) in your solution ?? 

@Jack D'Aurizio

Comment: @DwaipayanGupta: just use the substitution $u=e^{-t}$ and the integral definition of the $\Gamma$ function.